# How can I make a specific post page 100% after hiding its sidebar in Blogger blog?

Tags: html, css, blogger

I have succeeded in hiding the sidebar of a post but I would still like to make the page responsive enough by spreading the content full width on all screens- mobile, desktop, and PC.

This code I used didn't render the whole page as 100%. Please, I need your help with this:

```html
<b:if cond='data:blog.url == &quot;https://www.neuroscientia.com/2018/08/does-noocube-really-work.html&quot;'>
  <style>
  .sidebar {display:none;}
  #main-content{width: 100%; float: none; margin: 0 auto;}
  .main-content .column-center-inner {width: 100%; margin-left: 0px;}
  </style>
  </b:if>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reset width of the element `.blog-posts-wrapper`

Add this to your code above

```
.item .blog-posts-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```